# What does adding a number to randrange() do?

Tags: python

I understand that `random.randrange(6)` would generate numbers between 0 and 5, but why does `random.randrange(6)+1` generate numbers between 1 and 6 and not numbers between 0 and 6? What exactly does adding a number there do?

Answer (score 3):

It adds one to the result of `randrange`. `randrange(6)` is going to return a random `int` between 0 and 5, and then adding 1 to it makes it possible for the values to range from 1 to 6.

Comment: so would it ever make sense to add a number larger than one?

Comment: @user3131132: Sure, if you want the lower bound to be greater than 0 (and don't mind the upper bound increasing, too). Of course, there are better ways to do this in Python. `random.randrange(6) + 1` could also be accomplished with `random.choice(range(1, 7))`, for example.

Comment: Also, I think you can specify the bounds in `randrange()` (and `randint()`, a related function).

Comment: Im pretty new to programming so im sorry if this is a dumb question, what exactly is a "bound"?

Comment: @user3131132: A bound would be the upper and lower limits of a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

random.randrange(6)+1 is interpreted as:

Get random number between 0 and 5 (random.randrange(6)), then add one to it.

random.randrange(6+1) would generate numbers between 0 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

Since `random.randrange(6)` generates a value in the range `[0, 5]`, if you add `1` to that range, it will result in `[1, 6]`.

The minimum number `random.randrange(6)` can return is `0`, but if you add `1` to `random.randrange(6)`, the minimum number will be `1`.